# Saving an input value without database?

Tags: php, jquery

I know there are various ways to do this, I don't have much hands on experience saving data without storing it on a DB.

There is cookies, sessions.. and localstorage? Before investing into a method I want to know whats best for what I am trying to achieve.

**What I am trying to achieve:** It's quite simple, I have an input that has a changing value when the user is interacting with stuff. If the user reloads the page or leaves and comes back I want the input value to stick.

Gosh this is such a common question I know, but I am really not sure which method to use for such a simple task. I don't want to use something that isnt really necessary.

would `$_POST` still work even if the form isnt submitted? Really any insight would be nice :)

Comment: If you don't submit anything the server won't get it, and $_POST won't work. If you're comfortable with Javascript you could use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: you can store the data in session variables. Post values works only after you submit the form.

Comment: I dont know why I said localhost lol derp moment.. I meant localstorage.. so you think thats the best method.. I need to learn it...

Comment: Yeah I figured it wouldnt work without the form submitted.. I think session variables would be a good idea.. I have a rough idea on them, I need to read up on it. Just wanted to see what you guys think..

Comment: https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API

Comment: @DrixsonOseña Using $_SESSION assumes the data is on the server. The gist of the question is that it isn't.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Do you wish to only save to local storage or to a `.txt` file if a DB is out of the question?

Comment: Yeah @DrixsonOseña this is why I was skeptical I thought $_SESSION had a catch..

Comment: @MikeW, thanks for pointing that out. Pop the idea bcoz it has the PHP tag

Comment: @Fred-ii- Local Storage sounds much more intuitive.. I have seen many people recommend it :)

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Indeed it does, however it's not permanent, if that's your goal.

Comment: Sorry for adding the PHP tag but I am using OOP based structure, I do save other form data to the db, but for this instance I dont need or want to save the data, I just want to build a better user experience.

Comment: Yeah @Fred-ii- its a tough decision, how long does it stick(ill read up on it) but it last as long as a cookie? Dont have to answer that, I dont want to extend this chat, but I really need to weigh my options.

Comment: I used a github package that did something like this.. I couldnt figure out if they were storing the data on the database or not.. looking at it I see it seems they do.. actually.. maybe a database is the best way to go :)

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Since you're already able to save to DB, is no point to pursue what I had in mind, which was just a simple form that would write to a `.txt` file. If you intend on using cookies, then you can set one for as long as you want it to last, some right up to years if needed.

Comment: ok thanks @Fred-ii- I have boiled it down to cookies or just simply adding it with existing data.. I am building this app, and want to structure my data in the database intuitively.. I hope I can figure out a way to add it in nice and snug lol

Comment: I was skeptic to add to the DB.. but talking to you guys it actually seems to be the best route... thanks everybody...

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Makes sense, and you could also "storyboard" the way you would like it to be the end result. Meaning, think it through and visualize it, then it will happen ;-)

Comment: Yeah.. I actually saw how easy it was.. I got it added to the database it works nice, except (I may need to open a new question or do some googling) but would I use $_SESSIONS now to save it to the DB without submitting?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry What do you mean exactly by *"use $_SESSIONS now to save it to the DB without submitting?"* ?

Comment: Sorry @Fred-ii- for the late response, but I need to study $_SESSIONS but I am under the assumption it will insert data to the DB with an auto cookie?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Not a problem. No, Sessions are server-side assigned values which are not inserted into DB, only if "you" let it and the values you assign to your data.

Answer (score 0):

if you use sessions in PHP you can store all the values you need in the $_SESSION array.

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['foo'] = bar;
```

Comment: How does the input value get to $_SESSION?

Comment: `$_SESSION` array will be destroyed if the page is closed

Comment: I actually decided using a DB is best.. so $_SESSIONS may be a good idea.. Not to keen with $_SESSIONS I need to do some research.. BUT is $_SESSIONS used to save data to a data base without submitting $_POST?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Sessions are mostly used for login stuff to remember someone or having constant information passed to/from multiple pages. Unless others are not interacting with your application, then you may not need them.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry What I meant by "interacting" was, as long as people aren't logging into something, then you may not need sessions. If they are, then yes use sessions plus use tokens in conjunction with that to be even safer they won't try anything foolish like submitting things twice for instance. Have a look at the last entry here on the subjects http://phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

Comment: $_SESSION data is stored on the server with an auto-generated cookie to keep track of individual browsers. 

@Memolition, $_SESSION information can persist for several days if you configure PHP for it. 

Mike W, in my example session value 'foo' is set to bar. If you wanted you could set $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST if you wanted to maintain input variables across several page loads.